# React native fetching data from server using card view

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to fetch data from a server using card view react native but when I open activity it's still loading, where is the mistake in my code?

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
return (
  <Card>
    <CardItem cardBody>
      <Image source={{ uri: 'http://bprwasa.com/assets/frontend/images/gallery/kpo.jpg' }} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
    </CardItem>
    <CardItem>
      <Body>
        <Text>
          {item.nama_wil}
        </Text>
      </Body>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>
)}
```

and this

```
render() {
return (
  this.state.isLoading
    ?
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='#330066' animating />
    </View>
    :
    <Container>
      <Content>
      {this.state.dataSource}
      {this.renderItem}
      </Content>
    </Container>

)}}
```

Comment: Are you using `native-base`?

Comment: yes am using native-base

Answer (score 1):

In your case the problem is you are not setting `animating` property of `ActivityIndicator` to `false`.

however it is also important to note that there is still a bug until react-native version `0.58.3`, check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9023)

**Solution**

Use this reusable component it has the workaround `{ opacity: this.state.showActivityIndicator ? 1 : 0 }` 
Make sure you set its property `showActivityIndicator` to `true` and `false`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class ActivityProgress extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showActivityIndicator: props.showActivityIndicator
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.showActivityIndicator != prevProps.showActivityIndicator) {
      this.setState({
        showActivityIndicator: this.props.showActivityIndicator
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        size={isAndroid() ? 100 : "large"}
        color="red"
        animating={true}
        style={[
          { opacity: this.state.showActivityIndicator ? 1 : 0 },
          styles.spinnerLoading
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  spinnerLoading: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.!